# "Unsupported URL: https://www.youtube.com/"

Tags: youtube-dl

How to grab a youtube video if youtube-dl reports "ERROR: Unsupported URL: [https://www.youtube.com/"](https://www.youtube.com/%22)?

Complete error:

```
[generic] watch?app=desktop: Requesting header
[redirect] Following redirect to https://www.youtube.com/
[generic] www.youtube: Requesting header
WARNING: Falling back on generic information extractor.
[generic] www.youtube: Downloading webpage
[generic] www.youtube: Extracting information
ERROR: Unsupported URL: https://www.youtube.com/
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you include `watch?app=desktop`, that confuses the parser that presumes that the first query string is the video id. Keep the v parameter as the first one and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I just used the copied url from the video itself instead of the Header's url.

As in:

```
youtube-dl https://youtu.be/RpObAWZ0SKM?t=765
[youtube] RpObAWZ0SKM: Downloading webpage
[download] Destination: JAZZ PIANO EXPLAINED IN 20 MINUTES with Julian Bradley-RpObAWZ0SKM.mp4
```

Seems to be more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: It's not clear to me from the question how this is different. The question uses "https://www.youtube.com/" as the URL while this appends a timestamp. Was there something about your original usage in the question that was problematic (and not visible to us in the question)?

Comment: Since you are not quoting the original URL passed to `youtube-dl`, your error most likely comes from an ampersand `&` or other special character which gets interpreted by the shell.